# Limit the number of kafka consumers using the same group.id to 1 with static membership without kicking out the already running consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I have a kafka consumer with below config
Consumer C1:
group.id=abc
group.instance.id=1

If I start another consumer process with the above same config,
Consumer C2:
group.id=abc
group.instance.id=1

It kicks out the first process C1 with exception **org.apache.kafka.common.errors.FencedInstanceIdException: The broker rejected this static consumer since another consumer with the same group.instance.id has registered with a different member.id.**.

I almost have what I want, which is to limit the number of consumers using a group.id to 1.
Is there a way to make sure the already running process C1 continues, and the one started later(C2) is the one that throws above exception and is not able to join that consumer group

Comment: Have you tried configuring group.max.size (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_group.max.size)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a topic with one partition. Then only one consumer can read it at any time within any group.

Otherwise, I personally have never used `group.instance.id`. The default behavior is to rebalance the group, when a consumer joins, not throw exceptions. Adding a new consumer is a way to have a ready standby rather than waiting to recover any one consumer.

If you want to force a consumer to stay assigned to its current partition, look into using a StickyAssignor